# error in cmake compiling caffe and matlab

Tags: caffe

I am trying to build the `caffe library` from [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe) on my Kubuntu 17.04. I want to compile it with Matlab and have installed `Matlab 2015a` which is supposed to work.

However, when I run

```
ccmake ..
```

and change `build Matlab` to `ON` and then run `configure`, I always get

```
CMake Error at cmake/Utils.cmake:357 (message):
Logic error.  Need to update cmake script
Call Stack (most recent call first):
matlab/CMakeLists.txt:38 (caffe_parse_linker_libs)
```

Have anyone experienced this?